# Async Await Issue for methods with parameters

Tags: c#

I'm kinda new to Async Await concept. Have the following method in a Repository

```
    public TEntity Get(int id)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }
```

I call this method from another method

```
 BindingSource.DataSource = unitOfWork.ClientDemos.Get(newClient.ClientId);
```

I want to Async this as this could take a while depending on sever speed and such. How do I actually do this? Every way I tired gave me differnt types of errors. I don't want to bother you all with my wrong approaches. But here is something I tried and did not work.

```
Task <IEnumerable<ClientDemographic>> tsk= new Task <IEnumerable<ClientDemographic> >(unitOfWork.ClientDemos.Get(newClient.ClientId));
                tsk.Start();
                BindingSource.DataSource = await tsk;
```

It works wonders when there are no parameters to pass and the returning type is int. Like the following. This one works well.

```
 Task<int> tsk = new Task<int>(unitOfWork.Complete);
                tsk.Start();
                rej = await tsk;
```

Please shed some light to this matter. I really appreciate it!
Cheers!
Thanks!

Comment: Use `Task.Run` and also take some time to read up on this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: Show more code from the method that has `BindingSource.DataSource = unitOfWork.ClientDemos.Get(newClient.ClientId);`, this can and should be done without a `Task.Run` or a `new Task` but to give you a good example we need to see the method that sets that databinding. Also, you really should check the documentaion of the library you are using in your `Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);` call more than likely there will be a `FindAsync(id)` call you can do and await on instead of doing `.Find` on another thread. Lastly, what did not work about the example you showed that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Task.Run`

```
BindingSource.DataSource = await Task.Run(() => unitOfWork.ClientDemos.Get(newClient.ClientId));
```

You should also read up on [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are probably using EntityFramework, if so, there is a FindAsync method. If that's the case, it will be better to use that than Task.Run.

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetAsync(int id)
{
    return await Context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
}
```

Then:

```
BindingSource.DataSource = await unitOfWork.ClientDemos.GetAsync(newClient.ClientId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you don't `new` Task objects. You have a method return them (or use `Task.Run` to generate them). Forcing the API one way or the other is frowned upon; so unless `Context` has a `FindAsync` method I would just:

```
Task<int> unitTask = Task.Run(() => unitOfWork.Complete(whateverArgs));
await unitTask;
```