# Async method with parameters crash C#

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm using **C#** on **Unity** and **Firebase** for this project, but I'm not sure that this is a framework problem, more like async-approach-trouble.

I've a method to write data on my firebase database (**Firestore**), this is the method inside my `Database` class:

```
public async void AsyncAddData()
{
  User newUser = new User()
  {
      isConfigured = false,
      tag = userName,
      accessToken = ""
  };
  DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("users").Document(newUser.tag);

  await docRef.SetAsync(newUser);

  Debug.Log("Added new user " + newUser.tag);      
}
```

**This method works perfectly** when called from my `MainController` like:  `Database.AsyncAddData()`.

**The troubles begin when** instead of creating inside the async method the `new User` variable, I try to pass from my `MainController` an already existing `User` variable like `Database.AsyncAddData(this.currentUser)`, so the async method now looks like:

```
public async void AsyncAddData(User newUser)
{
  DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("users").Document(newUser.tag);

  await docRef.SetAsync(newUser);

  Debug.Log("Added new user " + newUser.tag);      
}
```

**This method CRASHES the entire software**. My thoughs after experimenting a little bit is that passing a "sync" variable like `currentUser` to an async method, is not loable. I think so cause if I do `Database.AsyncAddData(new User() { tag = currentUserLoged.tag })`, it works.

So now my question is...

**How can I pass external variables to an async method?**

*Already readed related posts and questions:*

[Async Await Issue for methods with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496468/async-await-issue-for-methods-with-parameters)

[Unity crashes on async programming with Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56635230/unity-crashes-on-async-programming-with-firebase-database)

[Async await best practices in asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

Comment: Question - why are you using async void instead of async Task?

Comment: the async void will return all exceptions to the main thread. Because this is not  supported by Unity it will just crash. In normal application it will throw exceptions at "random" places in the main thread.

Comment: Don't use async void unless you have to (exception: event handlers).

Comment: @PhilS honestly cause it seems simple to me, if I don't want to return nothing, just don't do it. But looking at all your comments, for sure I'll take a look at this approach.

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak makes sense...so the problem coul not be caused by an async stuff, just that I'm having an error like my tag being null, and the exception crashes unity, right?

Comment: Just ot have a better context, could you share the error trace?

Comment: Fixed guys, as spected, my newUser.tag value was null, and this null was extended to the main thread, and Unity crahes. I'll give the credit to the only answer just to close this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Task" as return type of async function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types#void-return-type

The `Task` return type prevents removal of `newUser` by "caller" method until async ends :

- you call `async`method with `newUser` from "caller" method
- `await` suspends processing `async` method and starts processing "caller" method
- the `newUser` is cleaned at the end of "caller" method
- then `await` ends and `async` method starts processing
- in this case 'newUser' is null and throw exception